# How do I create a conanfile.py based on my CMakeFiles.txt?

Tags: c++, cmake, packaging, conan

I've gotten access to the conan-center-index, and must now produce a conanfile.py for a library I'm maintaining, which is built and installed using CMake.

When reading the [instructions](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/master/docs/how_to_add_packages.md#request-access), You are told to go look at some examples of such files, but I'm still mostly at a lost regarding what I need to actually fill in and what can/should be left to the default. I also see some packages set member fields directly, while others define various methods which set fields, like `source()` and `build()` and `_configure_cmake()`.

Is there some way to automate the derivation of a `conanfile.py` from my library's `CMakeLists.txt`? If not, can I make do with just setting my package's class fields directly?

Comment: Have you gone through the docs "Creating packages getting started"? I'd recommend to check a previous version, like 1.39 https://docs.conan.io/en/1.39/creating_packages/getting_started.html, because the latest one is using some new tools still not adopted in ConanCenter, and it can be confusing. Maybe those docs help a bit to understand the purpose of each method.

Comment: @drodri: Mmm... version differences. Interesting. I'll have a look.

Comment: Another thing you might considering is creating a install target in CMake your your library. That way the conan recipe is simpler because details related to installation are handled by CMake.